# urxvt isn't launching with the tmux as a startup command

Tags: command-line, startup, tmux, rxvt

Previously this line was working and was launching the `urxvt` with a `tmux` in it:

```
urxvt -e tmux
```

… but after my latest install of 18.04.1 Ubuntu it's not launching any more. urxvt version is `v9.22`.
I've got it successfully started with those command lines:

```
urxvt -e bash
urxvt -e sh
```

but no luck with `tmux`.

How can I start a `urxvt` terminal with `tmux`?

Comment: `urxvt -e tmux` works as expected for me. Do you get an error message? What does `urxvt -e bash -c "tmux new || tmux attach"` do?

Comment: What version is urxvt on your machine? 
Mine is `v9.22`.

Comment: The default one for 18.04.2 LTS: 9.22-3